# How do I prevent one DIV from sitting on top of another DIV?

Tags: html, css, css-float, height

I’m having trouble getting one div not to lie on top of another div.  I have the following

```
<div id="navbar">
    <div id="leftNavSection"></div>
    <div id="rightNavSection">Logged in as Dave <a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/logout">Log Out</a></div>
</div>
```

with the accompanying CSS …

```
#rightNavSection {
  float: right;
}
```

However, when I add this div underneath, it lines up on the same vertical plane as the nav div.

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
</div>
```

Here is the JSFiddle that illustrates the problem — https://jsfiddle.net/z4rw9qj1/ .  If I add a fixed height to the nav div (e.g. “height: 10px;”), then the overlay doesn’t happen, but I don’t want to add a fixed height because if someone adjusts their browser font size, or I add other elements, then the look is broken.  Is there a way I can get the lower div not to trample the upper div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of `float: right` and you can fix that if you add `overflow: hidden` on `header` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/z4rw9qj1/3/)

```
header {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Don't ever let anyone tell you that you are not the man because you are THE MAN!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the z-index property ? It is a property that decides what order are the elements aligned in the "front-back" axis.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp